# in codeigniter, how do i load a library that has multiple directories

Tags: php, codeigniter, shared-libraries, directory-structure

for example, here is my path to one of my library:

```
application/libraries/samples/samples.php
```

now how would i load the samples.php library in codeigniter, since it is not at the root level of the libraries folder?  basically can i do this:

```
$this->load->library("samples");
```

will that load the samples library even tho its not in the root of the libraries folder?

Sorry im new to codeigniter, and the codeigniter docs do not say about multiple directories in the libraries folder.  But i don't see why they would miss that out, seems reasonable to include that info or support it.

Answer (score 2):

Just put the path to the library in your request:

```
$this->load->library("samples/samples");
```